# limit of a function with parameter "m".

Tags: calculus

I need a little help with this limit of function given by expression:
$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+mx}-1}{x} =$

How to solve this? I mean answer is $\frac{1}{3}m$ if the book is correct, and this example ain't complicated.
I need for sure do something with $ \sqrt[3]{1+mx}$ ,and I think I need to do a substitution
for example ${1+mx}=t^{3}$ ,but I ain't sure how to proceed with this can someone help me out and tell me what to do in next steps? $\sqrt[3]{t^3}=|t|$ or in this situation its pointless to use this ???

This will be useful knowledge because soon, after few more examples there gonna be  section in book-derivatives, and after that integrals, where you need to also use such tricks, but I ain't familiar with this.It is new thing for me, so all help is appreciated.

Comment: It is basically solved with Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^\alpha=1+\alpha x+o(x)$ with $\alpha=\frac 13$ but without this tool, you have to proceed with conjugated quantity which is a little less straightforward than with square roots.

Comment: Good idea! do ${1+mx}=t^3,$ and use that $\sqrt[3]{t^3}=t$ (not $|t|$) and $t^3-1=(t-1)(t^2+t+1).$

Comment: You could also use l’Hopital.

Comment: Taylor and l'Hopital are really overkill here. Both use the derivative of $f:s\mapsto\sqrt[3]s$ but if you know that derivative, simply notice that your limit is $mf'(1).$

Comment: OK. Thank you both,got it thanks for tip's. In future need to learn Taylor expansion, will be useful for sure when this year I will go on studies at university of technology.

Comment: sure, I was just wondering how to solve it, and what are possible path's to do it, with you're tips I did already solve it in my notebook. This link is great also Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(\sqrt[3]{1+mx}-1)(\sqrt[3]{(1+mx)^2}+\sqrt[3]{1+mx}+1)=mx$$

The limit becomes
$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{mx}{x (\sqrt[3]{(1+mx)^2}+\sqrt[3]{1+mx}+1)}}=\frac m3$$

Or you could use l’Hopital. The numerator becomes:

$$(\sqrt[3]{1+mx}+1)\prime=\frac 13 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(1+mx)^2}}\cdot m$$